# Is it possible to use Session in Ajax Call Web Method

Tags: jquery, ajax

I want to use session variable in Ajax call. But session is not accessible in web Method due to Static Keyword and without static keyword it is not possible to call web Method. I am using

`.Net Framework 4.5.1`
Is there any other approach to achieve same?

**WebMEthod**

```
[WebMethod]
    public static object UpdateRecord(string UserID, string UserName, string Password, string Status)
    {
        string Group_ID = Session["UserGroup"].ToString();

        int StatusModify;
        if (Status == ("Active"))
            StatusModify = 1;
        else
        if (Status == ("Inactive"))
            StatusModify = 0;
        else
            StatusModify = 0;

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["FAV-VAConnectionStringDB"].ConnectionString);
        SqlCommand cmdUpdate = new SqlCommand("Update_query", con);
        cmdUpdate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", Password);
        cmdUpdate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Status", StatusModify);
        con.Open();
        var refID = Convert.ToInt32(cmdUpdate.ExecuteScalar());
        con.Close();
        return refID;
    }
```

Comment: maybe specify what framework this is

Comment: I am Using .Net Framework 4.5.1